# What is the most acidic neutral hydrocarbon?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, hydrocarbons

This is a question I've been thinking about quite frequently. I had seen that this hydrocarbon has a low $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ with reference to the highlighted H-atom

[image: c]

Loss of the central gives aromatic character to the three 5-membered rings in the compound, contributing to its acidity.

Are there any other **neutral** hydrocarbons which are stronger acids? How do their $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$'s stack up against, say another organic acid such as acetic acid?

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, $\ce{CH_5^+}$ (methanium) is a superacid, but is not a neutral hydrocarbon.

Comment: $\ce{CH5+}$ is cheating?

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methanium. But the OP may mean a neutral molecule.

Comment: @KarstenTheis yep ;) Nice try though. I will read about methanium. Also edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I think you can get much further by drawing a neutral hydrocarbon which is initially non-aromatic, but becomes aromatic when deprotonated. Cyclopentadiene is extraordinarily acidic for a hydrocarbon, with a pKa comparable to alcohols. With some imagination, it's likely possible to set up a structure with cascading aromatization upon deprotonation.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto "cascading aromatization"  . Nice to imagine in my head.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto That's exactly what I have drawn! The question is: are there any compounds that are **more** acidic than what I've drawn.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb Well, what I had in mind was for the initial structure to be completely non-aromatic. For reference, cyclopentadiene is approximately as acidic as 9-phenyl-9H-fluorene, according to [Hans Reich's pKa tables in DMSO](https://www.chem.wisc.edu/areas/reich/pkatable/), even though the latter has far more extended conjugation. It's better for aromaticity to suddently appear, instead of existing aromatic systems merely being conjugated.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9212/can-a-organic-compounds-such-as-hydrocarbons-contain-an-ionic-bond https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/20283/whats-the-strongest-known-organic-acid

Answer (score 10):

In [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/9212/can-a-organic-compounds-such-as-hydrocarbons-contain-an-ionic-bond/49307?r=SearchResults#49307) a hydrocarbon anion called Kuhn's anion (**1**) has the formula $\ce{C67H_{39}^-}$ and reported $pK_b=8.1$, which would correspond to the neutral hydrocarbon having $pK_a=5.9$.  The anion, together with several hydrocarbon cations with which it forms stable salts, is shown below (taken from the answer referenced above; primary reference *J. Org. Chem.* 1990, 55 (3), 996–1002):

[image]

Comment: Ehhm, but the question is about *neutral* hydrocarbons…

Comment: But the neutral hydrocarbon is the acid.  It's mentioned here as the conjugate of the anion.

Comment: Right, but the illustration showing only ions looks confusing to me. Why not to draw alongside the actual compound you are posting $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ value for?

Comment: Not sure how to modify the anion, which would involve using CH in the center instead of the carbanion.  Would need a desktop I think and I cannot get to one this weekend.

Comment: How is this hydrocarbon so acidic? I understand that the $pK_a$ was derived via a practical experiment but how would one go about explaining it theoretically? Is it merely because of $\pi$-resonance? I don't see any aromatic rings forming/breaking to contribute to such a pKa.

Comment: Conjugation through the central carbon of the anion.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb It does aromatise three cyclopentadienyl rings, only partially though.

Comment: When we put the proton on the central carbon, saturating it, we fix a pendant pi bond to one of the atoms in each five-membered ring, so aromatic coupling cannot extend to those rings. With deprotonation to form the anion, the central carbon can donate a pi electron pair, which delocalizes those double bonds and thus allows aromatic coupling through all the rings.