Naming of acidic polycyclic hydrocarbon

How exactly should this compound be named as per IUPAC nomenclature, and is there any trivial name for it?

@Mithoron What else do you need? I have only asked its name.

Huh, I knew I've seen it before https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/124356/what-is-the-most-acidic-neutral-hydrocarbon

May want to check this out too. The answer has a supposed IUPAC name. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/129689/how-to-compare-the-acidity-of-this-multicyclic-hydrocarbon-to-the-acidity-of-cyc

I also just ran it through a computer program. It spat out "hexacyclo[10.6.1.0^{2,7}.0^{3,17}.0^{8,19}.0^{13,18}]nonadeca-2,4,6,8(19),9,11,13(18),14,16-nonaene" — talk about a mouthful. The IUPAC name involving fluorene is... more practical.

@Sonder From that post, I was able to tweak and "benzo[3,4]pentaleno[2,1,6,5-jklm]fluorene" seems to generate the correct compound at https://openmolecules.org/name2structure.html

@Sonder Your program doesn't use aromatic compound nomenclature.

@Mithoron You're right, yes. It was a script a friend shared with me not too long ago, so I thought I would put it through its paces. Unfortunately I only realized the lack of aromatic nomenclature when I looked at my comment again!

This IUPAC text $3a^2H$-benzo[3,4]pentaleno[2,1,6,5-$jklm$]fluorene like Loong said. Shame on you for doubting him, IUPAC is his middle name ;)

There is interesting trend in numbering complex compounds like one given in this question. According to recommendations given in Ref. 1 (pages 185-186):

The system described in A-22.2 (ref 3) has been developed by CAS to deal with complex examples (See ref 18). Their additional rules to number interior atoms for complex examples are as follows.
a. Starting from the highest numbered atom (peripheral atom or interior numbered heteroatom) the longest continuous path of interior atoms is determined and numbered by adding the letter 'a', 'b', 'c', etc. in turn to that of the highest numbered atom. This procedure is repeated at the next highest numbered atom etc. until all interior atoms are numbered.
b. If there are alternative pathways the two alternative atoms at the branch point are compared using the shortest path to the periphery for each atom. The atom linked in this way to the lower numbered peripheral atom is selected.
c. Isolated interior atoms and chains not covered by (a) or (b) above are numbered using the longest chain of unnumbered atoms with the numbering continuing from the highest numbered alphanumeric locant available.
d. If there are interior numbered heteroatoms the longest chain of interior atoms attached to the interior heteroatom is numbered as above.

Accordingly they have given the name for the structure in page 186 as follows:

However, the name, $3a^2H$-benzo[3,4]pentaleno[2,1,6,5-jklm]fluorene suggested by Loong (see comment by Mithoron) is not wrong either. In page 184 of Ref. 1 states that:

I1 there is a choice of interior atom locants lower numbers are preferred.

And one of the examples (page 185) given is:

I wonder, which one would be preferred. Since, two names given to same structure in same publication of IUPAC, I tend to believe both are preferred.

References:

Prepared for publication by G. P. Moss, "Nomenclature of Fused and Bridged Fused Ring Systems (IUPAC Recommendations 1998)," Pure & App. Chem. 1998, 70(1), 143-216 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1351/pac199870010143).

